# How can I use a reserved keyword as an identifier in my JSON model class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have never used Web API before, but I need a web service that will accept/return JSON objects and using this seemed like a reasonable thing. It looked pretty simple (if not a bit of overkill for my purposes), but a data structure I need to deal with looks something like:

```
{
    "values":["foo", "bar"],
    "default":"bar"
}
```

And so I went to make a Model object:

```
class DropDownValues {
    public string[] values { get; set; }
    public string default { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is that default seems to be a protected keyword. There must be some way to get around that, right?

Comment: may be try this one `public string selected { get; set; }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest to go different way. Keep your C# object model as much standard as possible *(I wouldn't use `@` sign and `C# keywords` as property name)*.

We can separate the serialized (JSON) world and C# objects - just by using the Json.NET features.

One of the simpliest to use is decoration with Attribute:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "default")]
public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
```

In this case we have to reference Newtonsoft.Json in the project. If it must be POCO, we can introduce `CustomResolver` derrived from `DefaultContractResolver` and define these conversions there...

But separation of concern in this case is a bit more pure solution, I would say

**EDIT: JSON Contract Resolver draft** *(see comments)*

Important NOTE: [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) is part of the Web API. Not only it is an open source, but even MS team bet on that as a core JSON serializer.

1) Newtonsoft.Json (as a part of the Web.API) is already installed in your solution. So you do not have to downloaded (nuget) separately. It would always be in your `packages` folder. So, to use the attribute is just adding the reference. It is there...

2) There is a small draft how to **do the attribute stuff, while keeping the POCO**. As I've tried explain here: [POCO's, behavior and Peristance Igorance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13632872/1679310), to keep POCO (e.g. we do profit from layered Architecture with NHibernate on a data layer), we can *replace* attributes with a `Contract Resolver`. Our POCO library does not have to reference anything

We just have to do extend the service layer:

```
public class MyResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(
         MemberInfo member,
         MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {

        var jProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        var propertyInfo = member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            return jProperty;
        }

        // just adjust in case if Property name is DefaultValue
        var isDefaultValueProeprty =
                  propertyInfo.Name.Equals("DefaultValue");

        if(isDefaultValueProeprty)
        {
            jProperty.PropertyName = "default";
        }

        return jProperty;
    }
    ...
```

This way we've provided the same information to *serailizer* as with the `[JsonPropertyAttribute]`.

Now, we just have to use it. There are many ways (e.g. global) but we can do it for a controller only:

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext context)
{
  base.Initialize(context);

  var jSettings = context.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
  jSettings.ContractResolver = MyResolver;
}
```

Comment: I do like this solution, but unfortunately I can't use Newtonsoft (at least not without going through a lot of hassle). Can you expand a bit on how to use CustomResolver?

Answer (score 18):

You can use keywords in C# as identifiers by prepending @ in front of them.

Answer (score 3):

The class `DropDownValues` using camel convention:

```
class DropDownValues {
    public string[] values { get; set; }
    public string default { get; set; }
}
```

You can use prefix `@` to passby but it is still not following C# coding convention.

The better solution which you can both avoid reserved keyword and still use C# coding convention is using `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`:

```
class DropDownValues {
    public string[] Values { get; set; }
    public string Default { get; set; }
}
```

And customize `JsonFormatter` to avoid convention mismatch between C# and json object as below:

```
var jsonFormatter = configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{  
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```