# Bind control to escaped property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having issues binding one of my controls to an escaped property. The JSON data I'm pulling into my app has a value that uses the reserved C# keyword `event`. To get around this in my class i've escaped `event` using the @ sign.

`public string @event { get; set; }`

But when i go to bind that property to one of my controls it doesn't seem to work

`<TextBlock> Text="{Binding @event}" />`

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704733/how-can-i-use-a-reserved-keyword-as-an-identifier-in-my-json-model-class Basically he suggests avoiding escaped property names, and instead using the Json.NET attributes to map "event" to a non-reserver property name in your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event is a C# keyword, nothing to do with XAML so just do "{Binding event}". Property change notification can use either.