# JSON and VS C# objects and names

Tags: c#, json

I need to serialize a JSON string containing the following:

```
{
    commandId;
    id;
    params:
    {
        userId;
        password;
    }``
}
```

The code I was given uses Qt and they declare a QJsonObject paramsObj and a QJsonObject cmdObj;
they fill the field values and finally perform a cmdObj.insert("params", QJsonValue(paramsObj));

params is a keyword for VS and C# so I can't declare a class with that name, but this is the way the device will understand my JSON strings.
I am fairly new to JSON and looked at the .Net class and the Newtonsoft library but can't find how to perform the insert of a JSON object inside another, assigning an arbitrary name to it.
Can anyone shed some light?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape `params` with `@` like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Params @params { get; set; }
}
```

This produces:

```
{
  "params": {}
}
```

Or use `Params` as property name and use [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm).

Comment: I ended up following what stated in this response:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704733/how-can-i-use-a-reserved-keyword-as-an-identifier-in-my-json-model-class

It works perfectly without adding the @