# Unable to map JSON parameter as a request body to POST API

Tags: c#, json, api, model-view-controller

I have below JSON which is to be sent as a request body to one of post API

In this JSON One collection is with name object

Now when I am creating the same class structure to accept its value as an input parameter to API, it won't allow me to create a class with name object as it is a keyword in c#

I have also tried with creating a class as Object (With capital letter O) but then it's not get mapping with Json collection field

below is JSON

```
{
 "id": "evt_1H6sEEKsjmsHEhuX87Sktxk2",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2020-03-02",
  "created": 1595225517,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "ch_1H6sEDKsjmsHEhuXn9w61svA",
      "object": "charge",
      "amount": 5997,
      "amount_refunded": 0,
      "application": "ca_3uEnjuTM2a0FYxKuLJJsbe7wql7nfwhU",
      "application_fee": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "balance_transaction": "txn_1H6sEDKsjmsHEhuXbsjV1sN0",
      "source_transfer": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can i see your api controller pls

Comment: API as follows

[AllowAnonymous, HttpPost, Route("api/v1/util/thirdPartyDiceGameDetailsByStripe")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ThirdPartyDiceGamePaymentDetailsByStripe([FromBody] Data paymentDetails)
        {
        }


public class Data
        {
            public Object Payment { get; set; }
        }
        public class Object
        {
            public string customer_email { get; set; }
            public string charge { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string receipt_number { get; set; }
        }

Comment: check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704733/how-can-i-use-a-reserved-keyword-as-an-identifier-in-my-json-model-class

Answer (score 0):

remove form body from your controller then in your ajax post try this :

```
$.ajax({url:'/api/v1/util/thirdpartydicegamedetailsbystripe/',type:'post',headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},data:JSON.stringify({id:'yourid, .....'})});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it's like after the payment gets completed this API is get called from that library used for payment and I can't change the library to use AJAX call.