# Dynamic DTO from nhibernate projections criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria, dto, nhibernate-criteria

I have a projection List in my c# code :

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(this.modelType);

         for (int i = 0; i < this.fields.Length; i++)
            projections.Add(Projections.Property(this.fields[i]));

        if (fields.Length > 0)
            criteria.SetProjection(projections);
```

if I don´t set any field in my projection my return is follow:

[image]

but if I set projections in my code, my result is follow:

[image]

How can I convert the list with projections in a Dynamic DTO object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need is transformer:

```
criteria
    .SetResultTransformer(
      NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean<MyEntity>())
```

or without generic

```
criteria
    .SetResultTransformer(
      NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(this.modelType))
```

The point with transformers is to use aliasing (see the `.As()`):

```
.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
  .Add(Projections.Property("Property1").As("Property1"))
  .Add(Projections.Property("Property2").As("Property2"))
  .Add(Projections.Property("Property3").As("Property3"))
)
```

Check more here e.g.:

- [How to partially project a child object with many fields in nHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26893475/1679310)
- [NHibernate AliasToBean transformer associations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24246277/1679310)

Comment: I need a dynamic DTO object .. the user chooses which fields are designed I return one dynamic list him

Comment: I'd say, that term dynamic DTO does not make sense. We either have DTO defined in C# as a standard class, or it is a dictionary. If this is a dictionary, the resulting `IList<object[]>` should be easy to convert into IDictionary. But still you need to know the keys... (like alias above) ... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13632872/1679310) few words about dto and poco

Comment: The second example help me.. tks

Comment: That is great to see, really. Enjoy mighty NHibernate Igor ;)